# PHP error message on array

Tags: php, arrays

```
 function ult_img_single_init( $content = null, $data = '', $size = 'full' ){

  $final = '';

  if($content!='' && $content!='null|null') {

    //  Create an array
    $mainStr = explode('|', $content);
    $string = '';
    $mainArr = array();

    $temp_id = $mainStr[0];
    $temp_url = (isset($mainStr[1])) ? $mainStr[1] : 'null';
```

So, I got this error on the line this line:-

`$mainStr = explode('|', $content);`

**Error saying:-**

> Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string

Any idea whats going on and give some help ?

Comment: what is in your $content??

Comment: ...and how that function is used.

Comment: show us the value of `$content` by printing it out.

Comment: I stayed here long enough, wait for the next bus.

Comment: @Anant I'll take a cab. One tends to wait too long for a bus.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  :):). correct

Answer (score 0):

and try to set $content with string value if not string like below

```
$content = strval($content);
```

Moreover, i think you are checking for `not null` on `$content` you can do it like -

```
//empty is equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false
if(!empty($content))
{
```

and flase is considered in following things-

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

[php documentation for empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: if  you got problem please feel free to ask question